# Php myadmin - my code won't create the table

Tags: php, mysql, phpmyadmin

I keep getting syntax errors when trying to create the table with PhpMyadmin.

What I am I doing wrong?

```
CREATE TABLE `cust`
(
    `cust5_id` Integer auto_increment primary key,
    `prog_id` Integer not null,
    `cust_no` Integer null,
    `balance` Integer  - accept negative and positive numbers
)


INSERT INTO `cust`
(`cust5_id`,`prog_id`,`cust_no`,`balance`)
VALUES
(1,217770,145094,-178.01),
(2,219885,145113,-390.86),
(3,219888,145164,-206.55),
(4,226227,145279,0),
(5,227700,145340,0),
(6,219911,145344,0),
(7,227795,145410,-44.1),
(8,227796,145472,0),
(9,219919,145481,0),
(10,225616,145604,0),
(11,219942,145668,0),
(12,219943,145682,0),
(13,219966,145694,0),
(14,219973,145731,-210.6),
(15,219977,145782,0)
```

EDIT: Changes:

Removed comma at end and no difference.

Error code is always #1064 or if I edit it slightly has problems with the "-###" entries.

Comment: did you try just run only the create table query?

Comment: Well what are the errors that you're getting? And for one, you've got an extra `,` at the end of your insert.

Comment: #1034 errors.@Khan I can create tables, but I want to the data loaded into them as well. I'll be deleting and replacing the data every 2 days or so for a database.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your comment needs two trailing hyphen:

```
CREATE TABLE `cust`
(
    `cust5_id` Integer auto_increment primary key,
    `prog_id` Integer not null,
    `cust_no` Integer null,
    `balance` Integer  -- accept negative and positive numbers
);
```

[image: create table in phpmyadmin]

and you need a semicolon instead of a comma at the end of the inserts:

```
INSERT INTO `cust`
(`cust5_id`,`prog_id`,`cust_no`,`balance`)
VALUES
(1,217770,145094,-178.01),
(2,219885,145113,-390.86),
(3,219888,145164,-206.55),
(4,226227,145279,0),
(5,227700,145340,0),
(6,219911,145344,0),
(7,227795,145410,-44.1),
(8,227796,145472,0),
(9,219919,145481,0),
(10,225616,145604,0),
(11,219942,145668,0),
(12,219943,145682,0),
(13,219966,145694,0),
(14,219973,145731,-210.6),
(15,219977,145782,0);
```

[image: inserts in phpmyadmin]

Comment: I did all that and recieved:
#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '
    `prog_id` Integer not null,
    `cust_no` Integer null,
    `balance` Integer  --' at line 3

Comment: is there any noticeable difference in the syntax highlighting of phpmadmin compared to mine (see image above)?

Comment: did you copy the SQL above?

Answer (score 1):

You have a random comma at the end.

Remove it.

---

Also if you are running this as one query set, then you need a `;` after each part.

Comment: I just copied part of the code, the comma was left over. My bad.

1 query set